# Import error: No module "coap"

Tags: python, module, coap

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from coap import coap

c = coap.coap()

p = c.GET('coap://bbbb::1415:92cc:0:2/.well-known/core')

print ''.join([chr(b) for b in p])
```

However, when I run it, it gives the following error in line 3 (`from coap import coap`): `No module coap`

How can I import `coap` in the script?

Comment: How did you install the coap library?  Sounds like it is either not installed or not in your python module path.

Comment: *Have* you installed `coap`? It isn't part of the standard library.

Comment: Thankou for the answer, but I've tried to install the coap library, but it's not working?
Can you tell me the command terminal to install the correct coap library?